# How do Async IO Coroutines get executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm looking at this piece of code from the example from [here](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#setting-up-your-environment)

And i want to know at what exact moment does the consumers() coroutine get called?

```
import asyncio
import itertools as it
import os
import random
import time

async def makeitem(size: int = 5) -> str:
    return os.urandom(size).hex()

async def randsleep(a: int = 1, b: int = 5, caller=None) -> None:
    i = random.randint(0, 10)
    if caller:
        print(f"{caller} sleeping for {i} seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(i)

async def produce(name: int, q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    n = random.randint(0, 10)
    for _ in it.repeat(None, n):  # Synchronous loop for each single producer
        await randsleep(caller=f"Producer {name}")
        i = await makeitem()
        t = time.perf_counter()
        await q.put((i, t))
        print(f"Producer {name} added <{i}> to queue.")

async def consume(name: int, q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        await randsleep(caller=f"Consumer {name}")
        i, t = await q.get()
        now = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"Consumer {name} got element <{i}>"
              f" in {now-t:0.5f} seconds.")
        q.task_done()

async def main(nprod: int, ncon: int):
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    producers = [asyncio.create_task(produce(n, q)) for n in range(nprod)]
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(n, q)) for n in range(ncon)]
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    await q.join()  # Implicitly awaits consumers, too
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    random.seed(444)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--nprod", type=int, default=5)
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--ncon", type=int, default=10)
    ns = parser.parse_args()
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main(**ns.__dict__))
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f"Program completed in {elapsed:0.5f} seconds.")
```

I only see this line triggering the execution for both producer and consumer coroutines.

```
await asyncio.gather(*producers)
```

I don't understand how until the await line mentioned above there's no execution in the background when tasks are defined and created in these lines( because none of the print statements inside the producers and consumers are displayed).:

```
producers = [asyncio.create_task(produce(n, q)) for n in range(nprod)]


consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(n, q)) for n in range(ncon)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `create_task()` doesn't start executing the coroutine immediately, it *schedules* execution in the background at the first possible opportunity, i.e. at the first `await` that suspends to the event loop.

`gather()` is just a helper function that waits for the given awaitables to complete. It doesn't prevent previously scheduled coroutines (such as those started with `create_task`, but also `start_server` etc.) from executing.

> i want to know at what exact moment does the consumers() coroutine get called?

Since `consumers` is a coroutine, while it's called once, it can suspend and resume many times, each `await` serving as a point of suspension/resumption. When you call `create_task()` it is placed in a queue of runnable coroutines. In each iteration of the event loop asyncio goes through runnable coroutines and executes a "step" of each, where the step executes it until the first `await` that chooses to suspend. In your code the step happens when your `main` coroutine suspends in order to wait for `gather()` to complete.

Comment: So let me get this right,
when the .gather() helper function is called, it waits for all producers to complete, and now due to the presence of an asyncio.asleep inside the producers, the consumers get called during the wait period?

Comment: @Red Yes, that's one way to put it. The way I'd put it is: `gather()` suspends the current coroutine until something happens (the "something" being all producers completing). Until that happens, the event loop runs its course, and drives **all** scheduled coroutines and callbacks, old and new, as they require. This includes the consumers and the producers, which were both scheduled previously. For asyncio to work, each of them need to suspend to allow others to run. In case of producers it's `sleep`, but they could also be waiting for a file descriptor to become readable, or for a queue, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely helpful.

Comment: @Red To further your understanding of asyncio, I highly recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) where Dave Beazley implements a simple event loop in front of live audience, being very entertaining while at it. Don't be put off by his use of the older `yield from` syntax, `await` works in exactly the same way, and in fact invokes `yield from` under the hood. It helped me immensely with "getting" the event loop and how it operates.